# Deleting data using string dosn't work, but with number does

Tags: php, laravel, extjs, extjs4.2, laravel-5

In database i have a table, where primary key is a string, which is inserted manually.
Creating and updating the table works fine. Deleting works only when number is set for primary key.
When i add for primary key a string "TH00754" and want to delete it from var_dump I get that the key is NULL.

In the function which is added down here console.log shows the key "TH00754"

```
destroy: function(btn)
    {

        Ext.Msg.show({
             title:'Potvrdi odluku',
             msg: 'Dali ste sigurni da želite izbrisati željeni Base',
             buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
             fn: processResult,
             icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
             scope: this
           });
        function processResult(buttonId){
            if (buttonId == 'yes')
            {
                var me = this,
                    grid = me.getList(),
                    store = grid.getStore(),
                    records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
                    record = records[0],
                    values = record.internalId;             

                    console.log(values);

                    Ext.Ajax.request(
                {
                    url: 'sku/delete',
                    methode: 'POST',
                    jsonData: values,

                    success : function(response)
                    {                                           
                        store.reload();         

                    },      
                    failure: function(response)
                    {                             

                    },                      

                });    
            }
        }    


    }
```

But the php var_dump shows NULL

```
public function delete()
    {
    $input = Input::get('undefined');
    var_dump($input);       
    $tvrtke = DB::table('sku')->where('material', '=', $input)->delete();
    }
```

The error is `POST 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Why does it work with number, but not with character

Comment: `Input::get('undefined');`? Where is `'undefined'` being set?

Comment: Try to give $input = 'undefined'; directly and try.

Comment: Input::get('undefined'); i did try and the same thing i get NULL

Comment: Its work fine in my similar case. Try to check mysql query directly to db. and print the query generating by calling these method.